# PorterStemmer error in android application

Tags: java, lucene, porter-stemmer

I am using *Lucene* for stemming of words.
I tested on a Java application (in the main) and it worked perfectly. However, in my android application (in onCreate) it is not working. Does anyone know why?
Here is my code in onCreate, in the main and error when it is rotated in onCreate:

```
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer;
import com.veryinteligent.jarvas.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class LuceneStemmer extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wordcommands);
        String term = "obviously";
        PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
        stemmer.setCurrent(term);
        stemmer.stem();
        System.out.println(stemmer.getCurrent());
    }
}

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer;
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PortugueseStemmer;
import com.rmtheis.yandtran.language.Language;
import com.rmtheis.yandtran.translate.Translate;

public class TranslationTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String term = "Obviously";

        PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
        stemmer.setCurrent(term);
        stemmer.stem();
        System.out.println(stemmer.getCurrent());
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace encountered at runtime.

```
08-11 19:32:55.455: E/dalvikvm(1148): Could not find class 'org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer', referenced from method com.veryinteligent.jarvas.activity.LuceneStemmer.onCreate
08-11 19:32:55.455: W/dalvikvm(1148): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2031 (Lorg/tartarus/snowball/ext/PorterStemmer;) in Lcom/veryinteligent/jarvas/activity/LuceneStemmer;
08-11 19:32:55.455: D/dalvikvm(1148): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b
08-11 19:32:55.455: D/dalvikvm(1148): VFY: dead code 0x000d-001f in Lcom/veryinteligent/jarvas/activity/LuceneStemmer;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
08-11 19:32:55.506: D/AndroidRuntime(1148): Shutting down VM
08-11 19:32:55.506: W/dalvikvm(1148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb6ff14f0)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.veryinteligent.jarvas.activity.LuceneStemmer.onCreate(LuceneStemmer.java:18)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-11 19:32:55.506: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[Update] I discovered I had to import my files by placing the libs folder. The problem is that I am having an error "conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1". Here's my console message:

```
[2016-08-13 01:43:12 - JARVAS] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor57.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:188)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
    ... 32 more
[2016-08-13 01:43:12 - JARVAS] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2016-08-13 01:43:12 - JARVAS] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

I tried all the old methods, does anyone know any new?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is pretty clear, as in the stack trace we find:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer.
```

Check your class path at runtime: meaning that you bring `org.tartarus.snowball.ext.*` and related classes to your Android runtime environment.

Therefore, check for missing dependencies (.jar files). For Lucene version > 4.0 up to 5.2.1, you should include the `lucene-analyzers-common.jar` file.